When moving vertex node, change the shape of each polygon that contains this node in QGIS
I digitized a surveyor's map, creating many polygons in a 1:7000 scale so that all points are almost in their correct location.
I switch to a 1:1000 scale, both image and QGIS screen and want to fine-tune the vertices. if a point looks imprecisely I do not want to unsnap the 3 (type T) or 4 (type cross) parcels, realign one to the correct position and snap the other 2 or 3 to this new node.
I know how to make a node blue (shift-click); sometimes I even succeed in including the node contained in an adjacent polygon (I only don't yet understand how I do that!). I even succeeded in moving the blue node (once again not knowing what I did exactly). But I never succeeded in picking one node and moving all other nodes snapped together with one move of the mouse.
This image seems to move 4 lines:

(note: the transparent image to guide me to the correct location is hidden in this example to avoid confusion).
But then releasing the mouse, I only moved 2 of the 4!

How do I select a node and all snapped nodes of other polygons, to move them ALL together to their new position? I use QGIS 3.34

Look into topological editing - https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#topological-editing

You can use topological editing (tutorial, documentation).
Click on the Topological editing icon (the 3-wing windmill) and then the vertex tool works as usual, but operates on all shared features (point line, etc.)

